# Unable to receive Android Firebase notification when App in background for a long time (When using Data)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using `Firebase Messaging` in our `React native` Android project. I can receive notifications no matter the app in what states but when using mobile data and put the app in background for a long time(normally 20mins).

When devices are using Wifi, all scenario work fine.

When devices are using Mobile Data, it works when app in foreground, in background(in short time). It works even when app is not running.

But when leave app in background for about 20mins, the devices are unable to get notifications. Any idea about it?

**EDIT:**
It seems only happened on Samsung devices.

Comment: are u sure app is not in killed state?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess it was killed. But even if app is in killed state, with wifi connection, push notification also able to be received with same device. A weird thing is, if I switch mobile data off and on, all notifications come.

Comment: oh if u switch off and on? ofcourse u will get the notification

Comment: I don't understand. when data is ON, unable to receive notification, but after do a quick switch from ON to OFF and OFF to ON immediately, notification comes. Why that?